# Curl waiting until timeout before proceeding

Tags: php, curl

This is the code I'm executing.

I have tried to set the timeout variable to 30 seconds and 3 seconds. The code does always get executed, but somewhere in the middle it stops and waits until the timeout before it prints "OK".

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.website.com/" . $settings["api_key"] . "/auth");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array("refID" => $row["id"], etc...)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "OK";
```

I'm not exactly sure how to debug this. Undepending on where I try to print stuff to debug where it stops, it won't print anything at all until the curl does timeout.

I don't know if it's related, but when I make the exact same request with a Java library, I get this return. May it perhaps be that PHP also gets affected by this "error" on the remote server and that's the cause? If so, can I escape this error somehow?

```
dec 04, 2020 10:48:54 EM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: AWSALB=hSCo...; Expires=Fri, 11 Dec 2020 21:48:54 GMT; Path=/". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 21:48:54 GMT
dec 04, 2020 10:48:54 EM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: AWSALBCORS=hSCo...; Expires=Fri, 11 Dec 2020 21:48:54 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 21:48:54 GMT
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like the server sends the response but doesn't close the connection afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask the developers of the service if they close their connection.

Answer (score 0):

After call of `curl_exec` check errors. It can helps to figure out what happends.

```php
if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
    echo 'curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Also it is recommende to set these options `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`,
`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS` to `false` to disable certificate check.

Comment: Thank you. No error occurs though, it prints nothing.

Comment: So it looks like curl completes w/o errors and something wrong with server. Try to use `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option and also logging options to write log to file.